# iPhone/iOS: Push Controller onto NavigationController that is currently not selected

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Within my iPhone App I use a UITabBarController that holds four UINavigationController. Each UINavigationController represents a specific navigation within my app.

Normally if I want to push a new controller onto the stack of the current UINavigationController I just do something like:

```
 // push another controller onto the current NavigationController Stack
 MyController* controllerToPush = [[MyController alloc]init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controllerToPush animated:YES];
 [controllerToPush release];
```

However there are a few places within my app, where the user is located within on navigationController and his action should change the selected Tab of the UITabBarController and push the controller there. I tried something like:

```
// Get a reference to my appDelegate
MyAppDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Change the selected Index of my TabBarController
[[appDelegate tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:0];

// Get a reference to the NavigationController whose Index within the TabBarController is 0
UINavigationController* navigationController = [appDelegate firstNavigationController];

// Push the newly initiliazed controller onto the navigationController
MyController* controllerToPush = [[MyController alloc]init];
[navigationController pushViewController:controllerToPush animated:YES];
[controllerToPush release];
```

But this approach doesnt work. The selectedIndex of the TabBar chances correctly, but the controllerToPush has not been added to the navigationController-Stack. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `appDelegate.firstNavigationController` is not nil?

Comment: Could you provide some more code from the Application Delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
[appDelegate.firstnavigationcontroller pushViewController:controllerToPush animated:YES];
```

Comment: Nope, doesnt work for me. Have you tried it, or was it just a guess?

Comment: Was a guess. But I met with this kind of situation before. But now I am not in front of my mac to refer the code I used. :(